# Insufficient arguments in function call

Tags: c, linux

I am getting error as insufficient arguments in function call of readdir_r . Function prototype of readdir_r is like

```
int readdir_r(DIR *dirp, struct dirent *entry, struct dirent **result);
```

where dirp - directory stream , entry is next entry in directory and result is the pointer to returned item.

I am using readdir_r as

```
int re = readdir_r( dir , &entry);
```

Do I need to pass all three arguments as prototype to make it work ?

Comment: Yes. You need to pass all arguments. For the third argument, you should pass a pointer to where you want the returned data to go.

Comment: you should pass all arguments but it might still compile with the two arguments if you declare the prototype as int readdir_r();  ....

Comment: Why would do you expect a function to work properly unless all the arguments are given?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to pass all three arguments as prototype to make it work ?

Yes you should pass three parameters to work.As you already declared function should Require Three parameters.

For example

If you have function declared as `int foo(char,int);`

Here you specified number of arguments and their types. you should call function with the same number of parameters and should pass arguments in the same order as same in the function declaration.

You should call above function

```
  int i=foo('a',1024);
```

You should not call above function Like Below

```
    int i=foo(10);
```

---

If you have function declared as  `int foo();`

Here You did not specify number of arguments.Then if you pass different number of arguments simply ignores.

you can call function Like this

```
int i=foo();

int i=foo(10);       

int i=foo(10,20);
```

But, These three results are same.  in these cases simply ignores parameters.

---

And good practice of declaring a function which takes no parameters and returns int is

```
     int foo(void);
```

if you want write a function which takes variable number of arguments see [Variadic_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Comment: Please expand on "... if you pass any number of arguments simply ignores."  Not quite clear what you are implying.

Comment: IMHO, the `int foo()` explanation is misleading.  The compiler does not know how/what type the function should get, but the function does _something_ was passed and can easily provide different results between `foo(10)` and `foo(10,20)`.  With such functions, the parameters are not necessarily ignored.  If they are not the proper number, type and value, the function may error.

Comment: Yes you are right here ` The compiler does not know how/what type the function should get`  it's how functions were originally declared in pre-ANSI C. In this case compiler did not know what it is . From C++ standard `If the parameter-declaration-clause is empty, the function takes no arguments.`  I am guessing, this might happens here.This may not applicable for C.

Comment: Since the post is C,, suggest making sure answers conform to C.  `foo()` does _not_ simply ignores parameters - it very likely uses them.

Answer (score 1):

With functions like `readdir_r()`, one needs to use *all* the arguments.

Sometimes the arguments allow values like `NULL` or 0, but it depends on the function.

```
int readdir_r(DIR *dirp, struct dirent *entry, struct dirent **result);
```

---

Function with a prototype that include `...`, like `printf()` allow a variable number of arguments starting at the `...`.  The number and type needed, again, is function dependent.  The correct type and number is impossible for a compiler to know (unless its a standard library function).

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

---

Old school prototypes/declarations like `int foo()` or `int bar(a,b,c)` only tell you the return type.  The compiler can't figure out much if the coder did the right thing.  This style is long since gone out of favor.